# I can't access any list of accounts when logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, network-profile

On my network profile, I can't access the list of all my accounts. In other words, when going to my [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/6241661/wythagoras?tab=top), then clicking on accounts, I get an error.

[image]

Some additional information for help:

- This happens on all profiles when I am logged in.
- This does not happen when I am not logged in.
- I tested this on Firefox, Safari and Google Chrome.

Comment: I am looking at this now.

Comment: @Oded Okay. I thought that the difference between logged in and not logged in was worth pointing out, hence the report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been working on the page and broke it.

Fixed now.

Comment: That looks fixed to me! Thank you.